# Grab major changes along a line

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, curvature

I have a line where there are many points along it. I want to be able to find the major changes in the line and just grab those points rather than grabbing all the points the line has. Here's a quick diagram:

[image]

What data I have so far is that I have calculated the Tangent Vectors between 2 points and then calculated the curvature between the two tangent vectors I got for each points. I then have another set of data where I calculated the 1/curvature to find the rate of change of the curvatures. I then plotted the 1/curvature vs the length at which they are on the line and found that if there's many fluctuations, then the line is not changing, however, if there's little change in the plot, then they are changing rapidly.

Data I have:

1. Positions in X,Y,Z of each point
2. Tangent Vectors for each two points along line
3. Curvatures for each two tangent vectors
4. 1/curvature

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to do line simplification, for which you could use the [Douglas-Peucker algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm).

Comment: @Rahul This sounds almost exactly what I'm trying to do. I'll implement it tomorrow and post the results.

Comment: @Rahul Algorithm was good. Exactly what I needed. Thanks.